# AWS: stop database when inactive

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need a database, which is idle most of the time, because it is a test db. The devs normally use their local DB. Is there some function like: when 30 minutes of inactivity -> then stop db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are talking about an RDBMS, then there is Aurora Serverless, with either MySQL or PostgreSQL Compatibility.
You can configure it to scale-down to zero "capacity units" after a certain period of inactivity.

One key difference between an Aurora Serverless DB cluster and a provisioned DB instance is that with a Aurora Serverless DB cluster you cannot directly make the DB endpoint publicly accessible (from the Internet).

Comment: but this can only be used, if my engine type is "aurora", correct?

Comment: i have already a postgres engine, i will need to migrate one database to another

Comment: but right now i have a Postgresql database hosted in AWS. I should migrate it to AWS aurora, right?